# Do out of party members gain any XP?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Specifically, in Chapter 7:

> Nia turns into a Blade.

So, when that member is out of the party, do they still get XP like a normal party member (since out of party members do get XP on discovering new locations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that party member does appear to get discovery exp. It took a while to discover a bunch of areas to test, but that member does indeed still gain exp.